# ATA TRIM Specification?

Tags: drivers, trim, solid-state-drive, ioctl, ata

Anyone know where I'd find an ATA reference that details the protocol for triggering a TRIM? I'm looking to discover what sort of structure/object/data I'd need to send in a raw IOCTL to get an ATA device to trigger a TRIM (assuming appropriate hardware/firmware support, obviously).

Thanks.

Comment: Windows? Linux?  Also, have you looked at the ATA spec for trim?

Comment: I'm looking for the actual low-level protocol - it's platform independent. IOCTLs are the same across OSes.

As for whether I've looked at the ATA spec.... that's what I'm asking for a link to :)

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were looking for a code sample (where you would use Linux's ioctl or Windows DeviceIoControl).  Added answer re: specs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find more than you ever wanted to know about ATA on [T13's website](http://www.t13.org).
 The most recent published spec [ATA8](http://www.t13.org/Documents/UploadedDocuments/docs2008/D1699r6a-ATA8-ACS.pdf) contains TRIM. It is the Data Set Management command.  
This [document](http://www.t13.org/Documents/UploadedDocuments/docs2010/e09158r2-Trim_Clarifications.pdf) (a clarification to an addendum to ATA8) probably has what you need.

Comment: Thanks. If only they had a PDF/DOC without the changes tracked for first-timers!

But you're right - it's definitely very much in-depth and *probably* contains everything I need :)

Comment: It seems the documents are incomplete? Sections 6 is missing from e09158r0, e09158r1, e09158r2

Comment: OK, http://t13.org/Documents/UploadedDocuments/docs2008/e07154r6-Data_Set_Management_Proposal_for_ATA-ACS2.doc + http://t13.org/Documents/UploadedDocuments/docs2010/e09158r2-Trim_Clarifications.doc is the complete package.

Comment: update your links. none of them work.